# Moment.js get the last 4 hour ranges

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment.js and I would like to get the last 4 hour ranges.

#### Example

If it is now `26/07/2018 02:39`

I would like to get an array of ranges in the of form:

```
[
  {from:'26/07/2018 02:00' , to:'26/07/2018 02:39'},
  {from:'26/07/2018 01:00', to:'26/07/2018 02:00'},
  {from:'26/07/2018 00:00', to:'26/07/2018 01:00'},
  {from: '25/07/2018 23:00', to:'26/07/2018 00:00'}   
]
```

The above is just an example of how I am wanting to have my duration of the last 4 hours.

So far I have tried this:

```
let current = moment();
//here am stuck on how to substract the above
```

It should be something like:

```
moment().substract(1, 'hours')
```

However, the above is subtracting one hour from `02:39` and will return `01:39`.
How do I go about subtracting hours so that it will give me the desired solution?

Comment: you can use `moment().startOf('hour')` to move back to 02:00, and thereafter use `.subtract(1, 'hours')`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `.startOf()` method in the momentjs library, to get your first `from` time.

From there, you could use the `.subtract()` method to decrement the times over the range that you require. Note also the use of `.clone()`, to ensure that the

So for example, a function like this would produce the time array that you require:

```
function getFourTimeRanges( timestampString ) {

    // Parse first "to" time for range, from input timestamp string 
    // (based on format in your question)
    var firstTo = moment(timestampString , 'DD-MM-YYY HH:mm');

    // Calculate first "from" time using startOf to "round down" to 
    // start of current hour
    var firstFrom = firstTo .clone().startOf('hour');

    var format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'

    // Add first formatted range into timeRanges array    
    var timeRanges = [{ 
        from : firstFrom.format(format), 
        to : firstTo.format(format) 
    }]

    // Iterate three times to compute and add remaining time ranges
    // to timeRanges result array
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        // Calculate "from" and "to" times for each of the remaining 
        // times ranges we want to calculate
        var from = firstFrom.clone().subtract(i + 1, 'hours').startOf('hour')
        var to = firstFrom.clone().subtract(i, 'hours').startOf('hour')

        // Add formatted time range to timeRanges array
        timeRanges.push({ 
            from : from.format(format),
            to : to.format(format)
         })
    }

    return timeRanges
}

// Then use method as follows

getFourTimeRanges('26/07/2018 02:39')

/*
[
  {
    "from": "26/07/0018 02:00",
    "to": "26/07/0018 02:39"
  },
  {
    "from": "26/07/0018 01:00",
    "to": "26/07/0018 02:00"
  },
  {
    "from": "26/07/0018 00:00",
    "to": "26/07/0018 01:00"
  },
  {
    "from": "25/07/0018 23:00",
    "to": "26/07/0018 00:00"
  }
]
*/
```